# Error creating GCP notebook: Error waiting for Creating Instance: Error code 12, message: GCE unexpected error: RPC::UNREACHABLE: EOF

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform, gcp

I'm trying to create a managed notebook for Google Cloud Vertex AI, and the application of the terraform template fails with:

```
    Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
google_notebooks_instance.instance: Creating...
google_notebooks_instance.instance: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_notebooks_instance.instance: Still creating... [20s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: Error waiting to create Instance: Error waiting for Creating Instance: Error code 12, message: GCE unexpected error: "Post \"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<redacted>\": RPC::UNREACHABLE: EOF".
│ 
│   with google_notebooks_instance.instance,
│   on create-instance.tf line 6, in resource "google_notebooks_instance" "instance":
│    6: resource "google_notebooks_instance" "instance" {
```

My template is:

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project_id
  region  = "australia-southeast1-a"
}

resource "google_notebooks_instance" "instance" {
  name         = "vertex-notebook-instance"
  location     = "australia-southeast1-a"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
  vm_image {
    project      = "deeplearning-platform-release"
    image_family = "common-cpu"
  }
  service_account = "sa-vertex-notebooks-inventory@gcp-api-rt-devops-poc-494d.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  metadata = {
    app   = "inventory-mlops"
    bu    = "supplychain"
    owner = "inventory-team"
  }
}
```

I'm not even sure how to address this, as there's no information online that I can find. Any ideas?